# Disable VBA UserForm 'x', but still allow Unload Me

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a user form that, when closed, needs to run cleanup steps. I would like for the `X` button to be disabled and/or not visible, but I still need to be able to unload the form. I've used code like the below, but it also blocks `Unload Me`.

```
'Disables closing via x button
Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, ClsoeMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        MsgBox ("BLOCKED")
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use the `UserForm_QueryClose` in such a case. Use the API `RemoveMenu`, `GetSystemMenu` and `FindWindow`

[This](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/apilist.php) is my fav site for APIs

**RemoveMenu** : http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/RemoveMenu.shtml

**GetSystemMenu** : http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/GetSystemMenu.shtml

**FindWindow** : http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/FindWindow.shtml

See this example

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function RemoveMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hMenu As Long, ByVal nPosition As Long, _
ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetSystemMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal bRevert As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Const MF_BYPOSITION = &H400&

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim Ret As Long

    '~~> Change UserForm1 to match your userform's caption
    Ret = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", "UserForm1")

    Do While Ret = 0
        '~~> Change UserForm1 to match your userform's caption
        Ret = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", "UserForm1")
        DoEvents
    Loop

    RemoveMenu GetSystemMenu(Ret, 0), 6, MF_BYPOSITION
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: What library is this using, and can it be added as a reference instead of using the Declare references at the top?

Comment: The name of the library is mentioned in the declare function. No. You have to declare this at the top.

Comment: Thanks. I've researched this method and found something that may work better for my case. Instead of disabling, I'll be using a boolean to determine whether the X button is accepted or not in the UserForm_QueryClose. I'm accepting your answer, however, as it answers the OP. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I know there are a lot of people who believe messing with any pre-existing UI for an application that isn't custom built is a big no-no. Probably someone of that mindset I would assume.

Comment: I would definitely like to engage in a discussion with such people to understand how is this "messing up" :) probably, it comes from a lack of knowledge I guess :)

Comment: There's a place for everything. Eliminating functionality from a pre-existing UI could be confusing for users and hinder the true intention of an app that we didn't develop. I do think, in very specific circumstances, changing or disabling parts of the original UI could provide a much needed adaptation that better fits the task at hand though, like in this case. Two sides, one coin. Can't have one without the other.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Probably a troll. I've never met anyone with the mindset steventnorris just described. I like your solution.

Comment: @dmaruca: Thank You. :) Well, I have met plenty of them. They really underestimate the power of APIs. I already know who downvoted me. I wanted to see if that person was decent enough to leave a comment. I really don't care about points. All these points can't buy me a Harley ;)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of giving the user a message saying he can't click the red x, trap it the way you did, and do the cleanup before unloading the form:

```
Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, ClsoeMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        ' run cleanup code here
    End If
End Sub
```

If the form has a close button that does the cleanup, then use something like this:

```
Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, ClsoeMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        ' click event code for Close button:
        btnClose_Click 
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

No need to go overboard with Windows APIs, since this is all built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old feed but you spelt `ClsoeMode` wrong. Simply change that to `CloseMode` and this should resolve your issue.